# How do I derive the Dual problem of a Primal LP with equality constraints?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I get the Primal LP in non-standard form

$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{max} & \sum^{n}_{j = 1} {c_j x_j} \\
\operatorname{s. t.} & \sum^{n}_{j = 1} {a_{ij} x_j} = b_i & \forall i = 1, \cdots, m \\
& x_j \ge 0 & \forall j = 1, \cdots, n
\end{align}$$

And I am asked to derive the Dual LP. So I standardize the Primal LP:

$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{max} & \sum^{n}_{j = 1} {c_j x_j} \\
\operatorname{s. t.} & \sum^{n}_{j = 1} {a_{ij} x_j} \le b_i & \forall i = 1, \cdots, m \\
& -\sum^{n}_{j = 1} {a_{ij} x_j} \le -b_i & \forall i = 1, \cdots, m \\
& x_j \ge 0 & \forall j = 1, \cdots, n
\end{align}$$

And now I use the transformation to the Dual LP:

$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{min} & \sum^{m}_{i = 1} {b_i y_i}  - \sum^{m}_{i = 1} {b_i y_i}\\
\operatorname{s. t.} & \sum^{m}_{i = 1} {a_{ji} y_i} - \sum^{m}_{i = 1} {a_{ji} y_i} \ge c_j & \forall j = 1, \cdots, n \\
& y_i \ge 0 & \forall i = 1, \cdots, m
\end{align}$$

I don't know if I'm hallucinating or something but this to me can be simplified as

$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{min} & \ \ 0\\
\operatorname{s. t.} & \ \ 0 \ge c_j & \forall j = 1, \cdots, n \\
\end{align}$$

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have $2m$ inequality constraints so you need $2m$ (different!) dual variables.

Comment: You could also derive the dual without first transforming to the "standard" form by directly writing the Lagrangian and computing the dual function. This way you can quickly derive the dual of any problem, with various combinations of inequality and  equality constraints without going through the standard representation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's rewrite your problem as (P):

$$
\begin{aligned}
& \text{max} & c^Tx \\
& \text{s.t.} & Ax = b, \\
&& x \geq 0.
\end{aligned}
$$

The dual of this is simply (D):

$$ 
\begin{aligned}
& \text{min} & w^T b \\
& \text{s.t.} & w A \geq c, \\
&& w \text{ unrestricted}.
\end{aligned}
$$

The only place in the dual that we need to take the equality $Ax = b$ in the primal into consideration is in determining the sign of the entries in $w$.

To see this, rewrite the primal as you originally did, as problem (P'):

$$
\begin{align}
& \text{max} & c^T x \\
& \text{s.t.} & Ax \leq b, \\
&& -Ax \leq -b, \\
&& x \geq 0.
\end{align}
$$

Let $w = [w_1 \ \ w_2]$ be the vector of decision variables for the dual to this problem, where $w_1$ corresponds the $b$ and $w_2$ corresponds to $-b$. We then have a new dual (D'):

$$
\begin{align}
& \text{min} & (w_1 - w_2)^T b \\
& \text{s.t.} & (w_1 - w_2) A \geq c, \\
&& w_1, w_2 \geq 0.
\end{align}
$$

Letting $w = w_1 - w_2$, we see that $w$ is unrestricted, so (D') is the same as (D). Notice that $w_1 = w^+$ and $w_2 = w^-$ are just the positive and negative parts of $w$.